# How do you make an iOS 8 widget appear on Lock Screen

Tags: ios, widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

According to Apple's App Extension Programming Guide:

> A widget may also appear on the lock screen of an iOS device.

I can't find any documentation on how to make a widget appear on the lock screen.  Anyone know how?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're referring to the Notificiation Center.  The NC can be pulled down on the lock-screen.  I could be wrong though, please link me to this quote.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you seen this may I ask? I think @varaosion is right, you are referring to the notification centre not the lock screen. As far as I am aware Notification Centre, Photos & Safari are the only platforms that support extensions in iOS 8